# Force Rewrite Query Var On Hierarchical (Nested) Page

Tags: wp-redirect, query-variable

I want to use a hierarchical (nested) page with a query var to pull dynamic content. I had things working when the page wasn't a child of another page, such as:

```
mysite.com/my-page/1234-my-var/
```

However, when I made my page a child of another page, my `query_var` no longer works, e.g.

```
mysite.com/parent-1/parent-2/my-page/1234-my-var/
```

My code

```
/* Register Query Var
----- */
function my_queryvar_params( $query_v ) {
    $query_v[] = "my_var";
    return $query_v;
};
add_filter('query_vars',  'my_queryvar_params');
/* Rewrites
----- */
function setup_filter_rewrites(){
    //add_rewrite_rule('^my\-page\/([0-9]+)\/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-page&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top'); // This works when my page has no parent, Returns a 404 when my page is a child/nested
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*)\/my\-page\/([0-9]+)\/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-page&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top'); // This doesn't return a 404, but I can't fetch my query_var using get_query_var()
    //add_rewrite_rule('^parent\-1\/parent\-2\/my\-page\/([0-9]+)\/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-page&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top'); // This doesn't return a 404, but I can't fetch my query_var using get_query_var()
};
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );
/* Force Redirect
----- */
function my_redirect_check() {
    if (isset($_GET['my_var'])) {
        if ($_GET['my_var'] != '') {
            if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) {$location = 'https://';}
            else {$location = 'http://';}
            $location .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];   
            $location .= strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?');
            $location = trailingslashit($location);
            $location .= $_GET['my_var'];
            $location = trailingslashit($location);                          
            wp_redirect($location); exit;
        };
    };
};
add_action('init','my_redirect_check');
```

I'm not sure if my regex is wrong (I have run it through a regex checker and it checks out) or if I'm just missing something obvious.

Would really appreciate any insights!

Comment: pagename has to reflect parent/child path because duplicate slugs are allowed if they have different parents.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case any one needs this:

```
/* Register Query Var
----- */
function my_queryvar_params( $query_v ) {
    $query_v[] = "my_var";
    return $query_v;
};
add_filter('query_vars',  'my_queryvar_params');
/* Rewrites
----- */
function setup_filter_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^my-parent/my-page\/([0-9]+)\/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-parent/my-page&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top'); // As @Milo mentioned, the pagename paramenter needs to reflect the path hierarchy
};
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );
/* Force Redirect
----- */
function my_redirect_check() {
    if (isset($_GET['my_var'])) {
        if ($_GET['my_var'] != '') {
            if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) {$location = 'https://';}
            else {$location = 'http://';}
            $location .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];   
            $location .= strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?');
            $location = trailingslashit($location);
            $location .= $_GET['my_var'];
            $location = trailingslashit($location);                          
            wp_redirect($location); exit;
        };
    };
};
add_action('init','my_redirect_check');
```